# React Link not updating view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having an issue with react router. Essentially if I navigate directly to route via the url, in my case:

http://localhost:3000/about

I do get the about component loaded into the view.

However if I click the link to about from home, the URL does change but the view doesn't. The about component does not get loaded.

```js
//App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link as RouterLink,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Nav from  './Nav';
import About from './About';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <hr />
        <Route exact path="/" component={this.Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }

  Home = () => (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default App;

//Nav.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Link as RouterLink
} from 'react-router-dom'


export default class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div><RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
      <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink></div>
    );
  }
}

//About.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>About</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... How did you manage to compile `Nav` component? It has invalid render implementation returning multiple root elements.

Comment: [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Creact&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=true&debug=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgF84AzKQuAcilQwYG4BYAKFEll25w4AGWDEA1nBQBnRBACuMJFFETuVWvSYsYAWjqLlugCaEG3C1yQAPPvGNJqKeQBt4aFzNkA5FADc4GyViY1kCIlJyAS4hZhDlAAoASmihWKQYeShiOATBNKEAHgQFJRUxSRgIAF4AIgB6WoA-AAlCJEL6ksNyiSb8guLS5VVKmoaUACNS5oBBacVO7rLR_pi0pM51inUgA)

Comment: I know this is a lot but could you create a codepen.io example demonstrating the issue? Right now your code looks ok.

Comment: I personally cannot find the problem from the code you posted. Are you getting any error on the console? Is everything building without issue?